# Magento 2 : Error While Preview Email Template From Admin

Tags: admin, magento-2.1, email-templates, sales

Getting this error while preview newly created sales email template. **Admin panel => Marketing => Email Templates** - magento 2.1.1

```
Error filtering template: Warning: Missing argument 1 for Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template::setTemplate() in vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php on line 187
```

Answer (score 1):

**vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/order_new.html:**

```
<!--@vars {
"var formattedBillingAddress|raw":"Billing Address",
"var order.getEmailCustomerNote()":"Email Order Note",
"var order.increment_id":"Order Id",
"layout handle=\"sales_email_order_items\" order=$order area=\"frontend\"":"Order Items Grid",
"var payment_html|raw":"Payment Details",
"var formattedShippingAddress|raw":"Shipping Address",
"var order.getShippingDescription()":"Shipping Description"
"var shipping_msg":"Shipping message"
} @-->
```

There is a trailing comma missing after "Shipping Description"

This issue also exists in the `order_new_guest.html`

more [info](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5101)

Comment: Thank you Prashant for replying, but issue was with xml files, i've overrided Magento_Sales but didn't copy all xml files in that once copy all xml file everything works fine, above correction i made before..

Comment: Okay, may be this will helpful to others.